# Creating a restful service with external provider for authentication

Tags: rest, oauth, openid, dotnetopenauth

[image: Simplified schema over server roles]

I would like to have some guidance regarding how to handle authentication for my restful service to be able to support a couple of different scenarios, see included image?
I've been thinking about this problem for a couple of week without finding a solution for all of the cases and even if I'll make trade offs I'll be running into problems

If we skip the Mobile application and the use of Curl, there's no need to expose the service to the public and it would be possible to use basic authentication for the server to server communication. But we'll still need to put some responsibility at the "Web site for ninjas only" to pass the (openid authenticated user) as part for the http header?

In this case we're using Google apps to manage credentials for our co-workers and I don't like the idea to manage another username/password within the service if it's possible to avoid.

Is there any sustainable solution for my dreams, so that I can build awesome features for the client and implement a tight api that manages the authorization for different resources for a specific user?

*Another possible to solution might be to integrate the service with the openid provider, but then I'll have problem with passing the user from "Web site for ninjas only"*